# Tableau line chart with complex conditions

Tags: visualization, tableau-desktop

I have data look like this.

[image]

I want to create line chart that show year_number on x-axis and show kpi_value on y-axis, but there're complex condition that I want to show kpi_value only from max month of each year, if you see on the data in year 2022 there're only 2nd month data recorded so the data point that might show on the line chart should be [(2020, 19), (2021, 44.2), (2022, 44.9)]

Comment: One way is to treat 0 as NULL and it won't show up in graph. Might need to adjust it in "Special Values (eg. Null) dropdown.

Comment: Actually, I treat 0 as NULL then how to only bring kpi_value from max month in each year?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using LOD calcs.

Create an LOD calc to compute the latest month with reporting for each year, called, say **Final_Month**, defined as

```
{ FIXED [year_number] : MAX(IF ZN([kpi_value]) > 0 THEN [month] END) }
```

And then define a second calc called, say **Final_Month_KPI**, defined as

```
IF [month] = [Final_Month] THEN [kpi_value] END
```

This calc will have the kpi_value for the last month with reporting each year and will be null otherwise. You can then display the final month kpi field as a measure or attribute, since the null values will be ignored.